# Close the shell from fortran

Tags: shell, fortran

I am using the `system call("action")` routine in a fortran program to execute an external command. I would like to close the shell if the command is called.
The example code I attached is:

```
program ai
implicit none
integer :: i

i=1
if (i.eq.1 ) then
     call system("exit")
end if

end program ai
```

I tried also with `CALL EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` but the result is the same, I can't close the shell in which I am working. I have to type by hand the command `exit` from the shell itself to close it. Any guess why this command do not work? While for instance, `mkdir`, `gnuplot`.. works?

Thanks !

Comment: "Why" -- because `system("exit")` starts a **whole new shell** and runs `exit` in that shell; it doesn't change the state of any shell you had previously running.

Comment: I'm not sure that can work. If you run this program, this program is a "child" of the shell, and when you make the `system` call, that in turn is a `child` of your program.

Comment: This is also why using `system("cd /")` won't have any effect: by the time the function has returned, the shell whose state you modified has already finished its execution and quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Fortran program is a child of the shell, and whatever is called from within by the `system` command is a child of the program, it's not quite as simple as what you want.

One idea is to use the fortran `KILL` subroutine (it also exists as a function apparently) to kill the parent shell. However, this requires the parent shell to give its `PID` to the program:

```
$cat my_kill.f90
program my_kill

  implicit none
  character(len=32) :: cPID
  integer :: PID
  call getarg(1, cPID)
  read(cPID, *) PID
  call KILL(PID, 9)

end program my_kill

$ gfortran -o my_kill my_kill.f90
$ ./my_kill $$
```

This should send the **hard kill** signal to the calling shell which would then be terminated. (I've tried it with softer kill signals like 3 (QUIT) and 15 (TERM), but neither of them worked, probably because the shell still had a child (i.e. the Fortran program itself)).

But of course that means that the program has to be started with the `$$` option, and putting this into a shell script will not work either, because the shell script would be executed in a child process of the original shell.

If your program does not produce any output on stdout, you could also make it just print `exit` to standard out, and then call it from within the shell with:

```
$(<your program>)
```

(including the `$` sign)

Comment: Worth noting that `kill` is not a part of standard Fortran and its availability will depend on the compiler being used and available libraries.

Comment: Similarly for the OP system is not standard and it's behaviour will vary from compiler to compiler and OS to OS.

Answer (score 0):

`system()` creates a *new* shell, and gives it a command to run. It cannot give commands to the preexisting shell from which you launched your program.

That said, `gfortran` *does* have a [`KILL`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/KILL.html) call. If you had the PID of your parent shell -- as via calling the `getppid()` C function -- you could request that it exit via that mechanism.